# element a: validity error : Element a does not carry attribute xlink:href

Tags: svg, graphviz

I created with dot a svg file like the one below (bb.svg):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="780pt" height="27pt" viewBox="0.00 0.00 780.00 27.00" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 23)">
  <title>A fie</title>
    <!-- Node1c -->
    <g id="Node000001c" class="node">
      <title>Node1c</title>
      <g id="a_Node000001c">
        <a xlink:title="tooltip but no href">
          <polygon fill="white" stroke="#666666" points="372.5,-19 262.5,-19 262.5,0 372.5,0 372.5,-19"/>
          <text text-anchor="middle" x="317.5" y="-7" font-family="Helvetica,sans-Serif" font-size="10.00">1c Set tooltip,no URL</text>
        </a>
      </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

(I slightly modified the file to get a MWE that can be used here).

When locally running xmllint over it (`xmllint --path tmp_dtd --noout  --nonet --postvalid bb.svg`, the `tmp_dtd` contains a copy of the files from https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD) I get the warning:

```
bb.svg:12: element a: validity error : Element a does not carry attribute xlink:href
```

How can I prevent / suppress this warning?

Comment: use a title element rather than misusing an a element to get a title.

Comment: The problem more or less is that it is a generated file and that graphviz `dot` places the node name as title, when I place the entire tooltip string (here "tooltip but no href") as node name it works but means that everywhere where I use the node I have to use the entire string (not that nice). I was hoping for a bit an easier solution e.g. by means of an entry in a `style>` like `pointer-events: none;` but this also disables the tooltip.

Comment: Either fix the generator or stop running xmllint as you're doing something odd and it's pointing that out, as it should.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably will do some postprocessing on the resulting svg file.